# Converting SQL to LINQ with INNER JOIN()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am struggling with how to write the below equivalent as LINQ.  Truly I guess I am only struggling with how I represent the `INNER JOIN ()` portion.  Is that called a Nested Join? Anonymous Join?  I am not even sure.  Anyway, big thanks to anyone who can point me true.  Even if it is just what this is called so I can BING it properly.

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, cp.EnrollmentID, cp.EnrollmentDate, cp.DisenrollmentDate
FROM vwPersonInfo AS p
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c.ClientID, c.EnrollmentID, c.EnrollmentDate, c.DisenrollmentDate
    FROM tblCMOEnrollment AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWorkerHistory AS wh
        ON c.EnrollmentID = wh.EnrollmentID
            INNER JOIN tblStaffExtended AS se
            ON wh.Worker = se.StaffID
    WHERE (wh.EndDate IS NULL OR wh.EndDate >= getdate())
    AND wh.Worker = --WorkerID Param Here
) AS cp
ON p.PersonID = cp.ClientID
ORDER BY p.PersonID
```

Comment: This looks helpful: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/12/joins-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: @David: looks like a nice site though I don't see any examples of what I am asking unless my ignorance is causing me to not understand that something there is what I am asking.... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put the inner query in its own variable. (It will be translated into one single SQL expression)

```
var innerQuery = from x in db.tblCMOEnrollment
                 where ...
                 select ...;

var query = from a in vwPersonInfo
            join b innerQuery on p.PersonID equals cp.ClientID
            select ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by writing a second method and joining on that method:

```
private static IEnumerable<Table> GetData(int joinKey)
    {
        return (from x in context.TableB.Where(id => id.Key == joinKey select x).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Then you can do your normal query:

```
var query = from c in context.TableA
join GetData(c.PrimaryKeyValue)
```